python set and get windows 11 volume
I have this script:
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL, CoInitialize, CoUninitialize
CLSCTX_ALL = 7

import time

def set_windows_volume(value_max_100):
    devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
    interface = devices.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
    volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
    scalarVolume = int(value_max_100) / 100
    volume.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(scalarVolume, None)
    
def get_windows_volume():
    devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
    interface = devices.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
    windows_volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
    volume_percentage = int(round(windows_volume.GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar() * 100))
    return volume_percentage

for i in range(0,100):
    set_windows_volume(i)
    time.sleep(2)
    print(get_windows_volume())

but sometimes it raises errors:
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable
======== Running on http://192.168.1.188:8080 ========
Exception ignored in: <function _compointer_base.__del__ at 0x000002B538E96B90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 426, in __del__
    self.Release()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_post_coinit\unknwn.py", line 559, in Release
    return self.__com_Release()  # type: ignore
ValueError: COM method call without VTable

Basically i use this script in a multiprocessing.Process with CoInitialize and CoUninitialize and safe release, but the error is still there.
Any help or alternatives?

I have downloaded some tools from https://www.nirsoft.net/

SoundVolumeView.exe
svcl.exe
nircmd.exe

python script:
import csv
import subprocess
import os

def find_active_audio_device():
    try:
        subprocess.run("SoundVolumeView.exe /scomma devices_list.csv", shell=True, check=True)
        if not os.path.exists("devices_list.csv"):
            raise FileNotFoundError("devices_list.csv not found. Ensure SoundVolumeView.exe is working correctly.")
        with open("devices_list.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                if row["Device State"] == "Active" and row["Type"] == "Device" and row["Direction"] == "Render":
                    return row["Command-Line Friendly ID"]
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return f"Error running SoundVolumeView: {e}"
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "CSV file not generated."
    except KeyError:
        return "CSV format is invalid or missing required fields."
    return None

def get_audio_volume():
    device_id = find_active_audio_device()
    if not device_id:
        return "No active audio device found."
    try:
        command = f'svcl.exe /Stdout /GetPercent "{device_id}"'
        result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True, check=True)
        return result.stdout.strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return f"Error getting volume: {e}"

def set_audio_volume(percent=50):
    if not 0 <= percent <= 100:
        raise ValueError("Volume percentage must be between 0 and 100.")
    try:
        max_volume = 65535
        volume = int(max_volume * percent / 100)
        subprocess.run(["nircmd.exe", "setsysvolume", str(volume)], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return f"Error setting volume: {e}"
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "nircmd.exe not found. Ensure it is in the same directory or added to PATH."

# Example usage
set_audio_volume(34)
volume = get_audio_volume()
print(f"Current Volume: {volume}")

I am not the maker of this exe tools, so use at your own risk.
